# Unicode characters does not displaying correctly in my website when using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have created a Google custom search engine. My site address is http://search.richinfosite.com. I have hosted it in weebly.com. All works fine except unicode characters. The logic of my search engine is when someone searches, the Google result will be displayed and the title and search box text will be changed to the search term.

I used JavaScript for this. But if I search other than English language the text will be displayed like some special characters. For example if I search the Tamil text "தமிழ்" it will be displayed as "%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D". What is the solution for that? I want the text to be appeared as real language.

I included the meta tag for utf-8. This helped me to display unicode text(included while editing the page in weebly website builder) in the page. But the Unicode text that is displayed using JavaScript does not work. Please take a look at my site and try to search in Unicode character and you will understand the problem or you go to this address http://search.richinfosite.com/index.html?q=%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D

### My javascript to change the title of the page.

`if (query != null)
{
document.title = query+" | Web Search"; 
}`

(query is the value entered in the search box)

### Javascript to change the search box text.

`if(query != null)
  document.getElementById("search-text").value = query;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `decodeURI` function.

Like this:

```
if(query != null) document.getElementById("search-text").value = decodeURI(query);
```

Comment: (`decodeURIComponent` would be the better function for query parameters.)